# Using config vars with angular and JQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, angularjs, web-config

I have an .NET application that uses mostly AngularJS, but for getting some things to work on IE9 we used sometimes a Jquery plugin to fix it (e.g. file upload)

Then on the other side there is an API that handles that application. But the API and the App won't be running on the same urls, so as good practice I would love to have 1 place where all the URl's can be set for where the API is where you can find the videos, ....

but how can I handle all this?

If i set them on the angular side, the controller is loaded after the JQuery,
so the value is undefined.
It can't read the web.config because it's just plain html files that are getting loaded. so no support from C#.
And didn't find any way on loading it in via JQuery.

Any suggestion on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can set it as a basic Object so scripts outside of Angular can use it. When you need to use it in the app, you can either require it directly or set it as a constant or create a service using it.

For example,

```
var api = {
  baseUrl: 'www.moo.com/api/v1',
  dogs: '/dogs',
  cows: '/cows'
};
alert('This alert was created prior to angular module declartion with your api: ' + api.baseUrl);


angular.module('myCheeseIsGoodApp', [])
  .constant('apiConstant', api)
  .controller('TestController', ['$scope', 'apiConstant', function($scope, apiConstant){
    $scope.apiConstant = apiConstant;

  }]);
```

Here is a plunkr to check out how it works.http://plnkr.co/edit/fnqcwHxgxgrZlCpryMiC?p=preview

Keep in mind this was just a quick way to show you how to use it, but you may want to make it a bit more elegant.